# Retain the duplicate row based on priority given in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","Q",98,56],["C","S",18,45], ["B","T",79,54], ["A","P",98,56],["C","R",18,45],["B","S",79,54], ["A","R",84,65],["B","Q",79,54],["C","Q",19,44]], columns=["id","prio","c1","c2"])
```

and I have a list

```
Priority = ["P","R","Q","S","T"]
```

Select the duplicate rows based on id,c1,c2.
If we find duplicate rows, retain the rows based on the priority given in the list which is present in column prio.

Ex: For duplicate rows of id A, if P and Q are present in column prio, give priority to P and delete other rows, similarly for duplicate rows of id B, T, S, Q are present in column prio, since among T,S,Q Q comes first in the list. So retain Q row.

Expected output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A","P",98,56],["C","R",18,45], ["A","R",84,65],["B","Q",79,54],["C","Q",19,44]], columns=["id","prio","c1","c2"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to ordered Categoricals and then use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['prio'] = pd.Categorical(df['prio'], categories=Priority, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values('prio').drop_duplicates(['id','c1','c2'])
print (df)
  id prio  c1  c2
3  A    P  98  56
4  C    R  18  45
6  A    R  84  65
7  B    Q  79  54
8  C    Q  19  44
```